# Google Measurement Protocol offline apps and event dates

Tags: google-analytics-api, measurement-protocol

I want to use Google Measurement Protocol to record offline events, i.e. take data from an EPOS system and track them in Google Analytics. This would be a batch process once a day. How do I tell Google what the date of the event is? If the console app went offline for a few days I wouldn't want three days worth of events to be associated with one day.

Comment: I have the same problem. Looks like we can not use MP for importing "old" data.

Answer (score 3):

Your best best currently is to use the [Queue Time Measurement Protocol Parameter](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/parameters#qt).

```
v=1&tid=UA-123456-1&cid=5555&t=pageview&dp=%2FpageA&qt=343
```

Queue Time is used to collect offline / latent hits. The value represents the time delta (in milliseconds) between when the hit being reported occurred and the time the hit was sent. The value must be greater than or equal to 0. Values greater than four hours may lead to hits not being processed.